# Azure CloudBlob.SetMetadataAsync not persisting data

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've read other instances of this question and took from one of the answers to build my code, but it doesn't seem to load any metadata on FetchAttributesAsync, even after adding Metadata and calling SetMetadataAsync

```
    const string StatusKey = "Status";

    await cloudBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();

    if (cloudBlob.Metadata.ContainsKey(StatusKey))
    {
        cloudBlob.Metadata[StatusKey] = serviceRequestStatus.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        cloudBlob.Metadata.Add(StatusKey, serviceRequestStatus.ToString());
    }

    await cloudBlob.SetMetadataAsync();
```

Additional Notes:
serviceRequestStatus is an enum and I've verified it has a tostring() non blank value.

I'm also trying:

```
const string StatusKey = "Status";

cloudBlob.FetchAttributes();

if (cloudBlob.Metadata.ContainsKey(StatusKey))
{
    cloudBlob.Metadata[StatusKey] = serviceRequestStatus.ToString();
}
else
{
    cloudBlob.Metadata.Add(StatusKey, serviceRequestStatus.ToString());
}

cloudBlob.SetMetadata();
```

In both cases, when I call FetchAttributes on a subsequent request, it has 0 entries in the Metadata dictionary.

Would there be any impact of this being the inherited class CloudBlockBlob?

Comment: what do you mean that cloudBlob.SetMetadataAsync not persisting data? no metadata is stored in azure after call this method?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstand this question. As per my understanding, you mean `SetMetadataAsync()` does not store the metadata in azure blob.

In this case, here are something you need to check:

1.Since you're using `Async` method, you should make sure the `Async` method are executed. As you may know the `Async` method is not running in the main thread, if the main thread terminates, there is a chance that the `Async` method does not have enough time to execute. So please add `Console.ReadLine();` if it's a console project, or add `your_async_method.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` in other projects.

2.You should also check if the value of `serviceRequestStatus.ToString()` is null or not.

If it's not the above cases, please provide more information so we can figure it out easier.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added some more information, please let me know if you need anymore details.  I know there's just something I'm missing/doing wrong.

Comment: (I tried using the ReadLine with the async methods and then waiting a minute, but that didn't seem to make a difference)

Answer (score 0):

Well, kinda a 'duh' moment ;-)

I realized that you have to re-apply the metadata if you re-save the blob, I decided to check before re-saving the blob and sure enough, the metadata is there.

Thanks for the help Ivan.

Comment: Great! And if my answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks:).